# Why do I get Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2?

Tags: java, swing, exception, concurrency, event-dispatch-thread

I am getting this error every time I try to update the data in my JTable:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.convertRowIndexToModel(DefaultRowSorter.java:501)
at javax.swing.JTable.convertRowIndexToModel(JTable.java:2620)
at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2695)
at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5712)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(BasicTableUI.java:2069)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(BasicTableUI.java:1971)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(BasicTableUI.java:1767)
at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:143)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:751)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1017)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:852)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1026)
at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:747)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:852)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1026)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:852)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1026)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:852)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1026)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:852)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1026)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5112)
at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:278)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1220)
at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5060)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4870)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:803)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:714)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:694)
at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(SystemEventQueueUtilities.java:125)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

The data seems to be updating fine, but something is going wrong and it's bothering me that it doesn't even refer to any of my code. After a while of debugging, I determined that the following lines of code were causing the problem:

```
public class LoadingLogListThread extends Thread{

...

public void run() {

...
int colNo = rsmd.getColumnCount();

while(rs.next() ){
    Object[] objects = new Object[colNo];
    for(int i=0;i<colNo;i++){
        objects[i]=rs.getObject(i+1);
    }
    if( objects != null )
        aModel.addRow(objects);
    count++;
}

mainView.logEntryTable.setModel(aModel);
...

}
```

The thread is created and started when I click on a button to filter the list, which then goes back out to the database to get more data that may be beyond what was already fetched. I plan on later determining if a new fetch is needed and only do the above in that case and otherwise just filter the results already fetched.

Comment: how do you update the data in your table?

Comment: See the last line of the updated code above for how I update the data in the table. Basically I just set the model of the table to the new model.

Comment: 1. That's a poor way of updating the table. Fire the appropriate events. 2. If you're setting the model on the table in the non-event dispatch thread and the event dispatch thread is painting, the underlying model may change which can cause the problem.

Comment: Ok, how do I set the model in the "non-event dispatch thread" ... where is that? How can I tell if the event dispatch thread is painting?

Comment: You WANT to set the model in the Event Dispatch Thread. Read up on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for an explanation and a solution using a Swing Worker.

Comment: Is setting the model considered a time-consuming task? "Time-consuming tasks should not be run on the Event Dispatch Thread. Otherwise the application becomes unresponsive. " This is from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html

Comment: There could potentially be the setting of 10,000 new rows to the model.

Comment: Wow, SwingWorker was the key ... I just changed my Thread class to implement SwingWorker instead and voila` !! Thanks guys ... I should have been using SwingWorker all my life

Comment: You should set the model in the EDT thread (assuming the table is visible), but for table updates you shouldn't be setting a whole new model anyway, you should be updating the existing model.

Comment: When you say you changed your Thread to implement SwingWorker, I hope that means you create the TableModel in the swing worker and then use the publish() method to publish the model so the table can update itself.

Comment: I'm not using the publish() method but I am using fireTableDataChanged() on the TableModel. I'm creating a new instance of the TableModel but I'm reloading entirely new data into the model so I make a new call to the db and store the results in the already existing instance of the TableModel ... at this point I call fireTableDataChanged and the JTable updates extremely quickly ... much quicker than it ever did in the past. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Have you tryied updating the current model data insteead of creating a new table model?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be updating the model on the Event Dispatch Thread. You're correct to spawn a new thread to perform some of the work, especially since data is being fetched from a database. Try this:

```
public class LoadingLogListThread extends Thread{

...

public void run() {

...
int colNo = rsmd.getColumnCount();

while(rs.next() ){
    Object[] objects = new Object[colNo];
    for(int i=0;i<colNo;i++){
        objects[i]=rs.getObject(i+1);
    }
    if( objects != null )
        aModel.addRow(objects);
    count++;
}

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mainView.logEntryTable.setModel(aModel);
    }

});

...

}
```

Comment: I tried now to create the row with invoke later but I still get the exception.
If I use invoke later I get the exception reproducable.

Comment: For me I had to change RowsInserted to TableDataChanged. 
//     fireTableRowsInserted( getRowCount()-1, getRowCount()-1 );
     fireTableDataChanged(); /*avoids index array out of bounds exception in the default row sorter*/